# JQuery Autocomplete Where the Results are Links

Tags: html, jquery, autocomplete, hyperlink

I am trying to create a JQuery Autocomplete box where the words being suggested for autcomplete are links (similar to what happens on Facebook or Quora).

Basically, I want the autocomplete results to drop down and I want people to be able to click on them and be navigated to a different page. Here is the code I am currently using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["Spencer Kline", "Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<input id="autocomplete" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is simple. Change your source to an array of objects, such as:

```
var source = [ { value: "www.foo.com",
                 label: "Spencer Kline"
               },
               { value: "www.example.com",
                 label: "James Bond"
               },
               ...
             ];
```

The just use the select method to redirect to the 'value', e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am new to JQuery, where would I place the redirect statement in the code?

Comment: @Spencer - I've just added a fiddle. That should make it clear.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it. However, I am such a newbie that I can't get it work. I place the JQuery stuff in the <head> and the HTML stuff in the <body>. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Also will this allow me to link to HTML pages on my local host?

Comment: @Spencer - yes it will. Do you have a link to your test site? I would suggest working through this yourself until you get it (the hard way - ugh :) Also, you *are* talking about jQuery UI Autocomplete, right?

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I didn't change the source, and changed the select to:  `window.location.href = "/search.php?keyword="+ui.item.value;`

Comment: also, to measure if autocomplete suggestions are actually used, I added an index to the url: `?keyword="+ui.item.value+"&suggest="+ui.item.index`. Server logs can be searched later for urls with the `suggest` parameter.

Comment: a supplementary question: is it possible to force the user not to enter anything other than the selection offered with this code

Comment: I had to use `window.location.pathname` to get consistent behavior across all my app's pages.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without jQuery, using only datalist attribute??