# javascript: Making items in searchlist clickable

Tags: javascript, html, list

So I was looking for an easy way(no use of database) to search items through a list with the help of a search bar.

I found this --- [jsfiddle.net/TrRMG/90/](http://jsfiddle.net/TrRMG/90/)

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<br>
<select id="customer" size="1">
  <option value=100>Alice</option>
  <option value=101>Bob</option>
  <option value=102>Carla</option>
  <option value=103>Dan</option>
  <option value=104>Eve</option>
</select>
```

Is there anyway to alter the code to make the searched items clickable?

Example:

Lets say I type in bob.
Bob comes up in the second box, I click on it and it takes me to a page/website.

Is this possible? if so, how?

Comment: See something along these lines. It uses jQuery, but writing something like this from scratch would take a little while and probably ins't worth the effort. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536055/jquery-autocomplete-where-the-results-are-links

Comment: http://tablefilter.free.fr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/TrRMG/107/

Added `link="http://jsfiddle.net/TrRMG/107/"` to each `<option>` tag and the following jQuery function

```
$('#customer option').click(function(){
    window.location='$(this).attr(link)'; 
});
```

It works kinda wonky because jsfiddle is working in iframes but implemented onto an actual page it should work just fine

Comment: doesnt work for me...

Comment: Huh, you're right, its not working when you search by anything... but it works when you don't have anything in the search bar. That's really weird.