# Autocomplete textbox with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a autocomplete or auto suggest textbox with hyperlink on each suggested value like if we g it show result google or when we select google it redirect to google.com.

Please any one help me out of this problem I stuck in serious problem I m new in this field so please please help me and guide me with code snippet or fiddle

many thank's in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Autocomplete Where the Results are Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536055/jquery-autocomplete-where-the-results-are-links)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give a snippet of code that i use

```
function updateAutoSrch()
 {
          $("#searchpro").autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "search",
            data: {proname: proname},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                   return {
                       label: item.user_name,
                       value: item.user_name,
                       userid: item.user_id,
                       profile_image_path: item.profile_image_path
                   }
               }));
            }

            });
       }
  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
             var inner_html = "<a href='"+siteurl+"/user/"+item.userid+"'>"+ "</a>";
             return $("<li style = 'padding:20px 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0 0;height:50px;' ></li>")
                     .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                     .append(inner_html)
                     .appendTo(ul);
         };
 }
```

using `.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem` we are modifying the default functionality of the autoload in jquery ui. item contains all the objects that are returned by success callback

Comment: Thanks @Sourabh for your help at-least you trying to me out of this problem xcept above peoples. Soo many thanks.

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma can you also post code behind & how to get result from database