# How to print link into dropdown with php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get link into dropdown menu, in other words when user type something into input field, he will get suggestion but that suggestion must be link. I tried with json_encode and in this variant i got only text, also I tried to generate link from php but got error in that case. Somebody to help ? Thanks.

HTML Code

```
 <input id="handleSearchBtn" type="text" class="form-control ui-widget">
```

jQuery Code with PHP

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
        <?php
            $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
            $sql = "SELECT CRMContact FROM tb_users WHERE id = " . $_REQUEST["viewId"];
            $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
                $crm = "<a href='view_user.php'>" . $row->CRMContact . "</a>";
            } else {
                $crm = "";
            }
            //this will output only text
            // when remove json_encode i got error
            // SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
                echo json_encode($crm);
        ?>

    ];
    $( "#handleSearchBtn" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Comment: you want to display only $row->CRMContact value ex. xyz or full anchor tag ?? what's output that you are getting , show the output.

Comment: anchor with $row->CRMContact value, <a href='view_user.php'>" . $row->CRMContact . "</a>, i got only value when remove a tags and put only $row->CRMCOntact but i want link with this value

Comment: why are you using echo json_encode when you want to use that value for html element , just echo should be fine , try it

Comment: when remove json_encode i get error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: i have tried your php code , it's working file..

Comment: you got link into dropdown menu ? for me doesn't work

Comment: yes, but i got the full link like '<a href='view_user.php'>anything</a>' . do you want only link name ?

Comment: i also get that, but i want link which can be used like a link, display only value of $row->CRMContact but  link, not text

Comment: do you want to redirect user when user click on it ? then you can use jquery on click event for that.

Comment: this will help...[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536055/jquery-autocomplete-where-the-results-are-links

Comment: i tried that, but i must generate link from php so i can get data from db, this still not working when generate link from php

Comment: I succed, thanks for help.

Comment: my pleasure ... :)